# PySide: emit signal to QLabel setText()

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qlabel

I am trying to update QLabel widget from a thread by emitting a signal from thread, but it seems not working. Here is the code snippet:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import mainGui
import os

class Program(QDialog, mainGui.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Program, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.workerThread = WorkerThread()
        self.connect(self.updateButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getDists)
        ...some other signals here...
        self.connect(self.label, SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), self.updateLabel)
        self.connect(self.workerThread, SIGNAL("exception()"), self.threadDone)

    def getDists(self):
         self.workerThread.start()

    def updateLabel(self, text):
         self.label.setText(text)    

    def threadDone(self):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "blaa", "blaa blaa") 

class WorkerThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None ):

        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):                      

        try:
           ..some code...           
           self.emit(SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), "Updating...")
           ..more code here..                     

        except OSError as e:
            self.emit(SIGNAL("exception()")) 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Program()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

The problem is that the GUI doesn't update the QLabel widget with the text "Updating..." when program is in the try-block. However, this works fine and the GUI is updated:

```
...
def run(self):                      

        try:
           ..some code...           
           form.label.setText("Updating...")
           #self.emit(SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), "Updating...")
           #and in this case, self.connect(self.label, SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), self.updateLabel) is also commented out
           ..more code here..
```

So, I am bit confused why emitting the signal doesn't work, because emitting the signal in case of exception works fine.

Comment: Found the reason after looking at the code snippet above: it should be self.connect(self.workerThread, SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), self.updateLabel) instead of self.connect(self.label, SIGNAL("changed(QString)"), self.updateLabel). I was really blind for my code, lol. Sometimes this is a bit frustrating.. But it is now working well.

Comment: It might be less frustrating if you used the [New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: Thanks - I will have a look at that.